# Showing that the sheaf-functor $\epsilon: \tilde{\sf C} \to \tilde{\tilde{\sf C}}$ is an equivalence

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $(\mathsf C,J)$ be a site. Then we have the category of sheaves $\tilde{\mathsf C}$ and the category $\tilde{\tilde{\sf C}}$ of sheaves over $\tilde{\sf C}$ (both considered with the canonical topology).

There is a functor $\epsilon: \tilde{\sf C} \to \tilde{\tilde{\sf C}}$, which is the composition $\bf ay$ of the Yoneda functor $\mathbf y_C = \operatorname{Hom}(-,C)$ and the associated sheaf functor $\mathbf a$.

I have seen it repeatedly claimed that $\epsilon$ is an equivalence, but I lack background to understand the proof in the *Elephant* (C2.2.7). Nonetheless, Makkai and Reyes claim in *First Order Categorical Logic* that "it is not hard to show Lemma 1.3.14 directly" (where 1.3.14 is the statement that $\epsilon$ is an equivalence).

---

So I tried to prove it directly; obviously the difficulty lies in defining the functor $R$ that forms an equivalence together with $\epsilon$. Here is my attempt:

Let $\mathcal S$ be a sheaf over $\tilde{\sf C}$ (so an object of $\tilde{\tilde{\sf C}}$); then $\mathcal S = \varinjlim_i \operatorname{Hom}(-,F_i)$ for some objects $F_i$ of $\tilde{\sf C}$. For any $F$, now, $\mathcal SF$ is an equivalence class of natural transformations $[\eta: F \to F_i]$. So now I let:

$$R\mathcal S = G, GC = \left\{\left([\eta_C: FC \to F_iC],x\right) \mid F \in \operatorname{ob}\tilde{\sf C}, x \in FC\right\}$$

and for $f:D \to C$, define $Gf: GC \to GD$ by $$Gf([\eta_C:FC\to F_iC],x) = ([\eta_D:FD \to F_iD],Ff(x))$$

So I *think* this will provide an equivalence, but I'm not really sure because of the multitude of supposedly obvious claims (e.g. about well-definedness, and that $G$ is a sheaf).

---

My question now has two parts:

1. Is this definition going to work? What should I pay careful attention to?
2. If not, is there any other *explicit* construction of the functor $R$?

Comment: You might want to try to show that $\epsilon$ is fully faithful and essentially surjective instead of finding an explicit inverse. The fully faithfulness seems to come from adjunction and Yoneda's lemma (I might be mistaken, I didn't write it down). It remains to show the essentially surjective part.

Comment: @Pece That might provide conceptual simplicity. But it still remains to exhibit a sheaf $F$ such that $\mathcal S \simeq \mathbf y_F$, which seems to lie at the core of the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simplicity, assume $(\mathbb{C}, J)$ is a small subcanonical site. The quasi-inverse of the embedding $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J) \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J))$ has a very simple description: it is the functor that sends a sheaf $F : \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ to its restriction along the embedding $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)$.

Indeed, suppose $F : \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is a sheaf. I claim $F$ is determined up to unique isomorphism by its restriction along the embedding $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)$. Indeed, let $X : \mathbb{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be a $J$-sheaf. Then $X$ is the colimit of a canonical small diagram of representable sheaves on $(\mathbb{C}, J)$ in a canonical way. Consider the colimiting cocone on $X$: it is a universal effective epimorphic family and is therefore a covering family in the canonical topology on $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)$. Thus, $F (X)$ is indeed determined up to unique isomorphism by the restriction of $F$ to $\mathbb{C}$. We must also show that the restriction is actually a sheaf on $(\mathbb{C}, J)$; but this is true because $J$-covering sieves in $\mathbb{C}$ become universal effective epimorphic families in $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)$.

Thus we obtain a functor $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)) \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J)$ that is left quasi-inverse to the embedding $\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J) \to \mathbf{Sh}(\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, J))$, and the argument above shows that it is also a right quasi-inverse.

Comment: Thank you! That was simpler than I had thought and than I hoped for. I'll wait two more days before awarding the bounty; there may come other answers.

Comment: Well, sometimes special cases are easier to prove. The general version of the theorem (e.g. the cited one in the Elephant) is harder – I suspect there isn't an explicit description of the quasi-inverse in that case.