# Repeating the Yoneda embedding

Tags: category-theory

Let $\cal C_1$ be a category.

Let $Y_1 : \cal C_1 \rightarrow \operatorname{Set}^{\mathcal{C}_1^{\operatorname{op}}}$ be the Yoneda embedding. Name the category on the right side $\cal C_2$.

Now do this again. Let $Y_2 : \cal C_2 \rightarrow \operatorname{Set}^{\mathcal{C}_2^{\operatorname{op}}}$ be the Yoneda embedding of $\cal C_2$ inside its functor category. Call the category on the right side $\cal C_3$.

The question is:

> Is $Y_2 : \cal C_2 \rightarrow \cal C_3$ an equivalence(or isomorphism) of categories?

Comment: It becomes true if you introduce topologies and consider sheaves instead of presheaves (see SGA).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Is there a non-French reference for the same?

Comment: Try to look at the usual books on topos theory (*Sketches of an elephant* or *Sheaves in geometry and logic*).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: These are interesting references. Thanks.

Comment: A proof of the theorem Martin is referring to is sketched [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/473614/5191).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any category. Then the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ is *never* an equivalence. Indeed, consider the functor $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ that sends everything to the empty set. This is not isomorphic to any representable functor, because $\mathcal{C}(-, c)$ is non-empty at $c$. Thus the Yoneda embedding is not essentially surjective on objects.

Comment: Is this the only way this occurs or are there deeper issues? To be more precise, suppose we throw out the functor in your answer from the categories $\cal C_2$ and $\cal C_3$. Then is the statement true?

Comment: There are other problems; this is just the easiest one to explain. The main issue is that the Yoneda embedding rarely preserves colimits – so unlike most "completion" operations you may be familiar with, this one is never idempotent.

Comment: Are you the same person as the author of this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5227 ? And if so, is it in any way at least "sort of" related to the issues addressed there?

Comment: Yes, there are also size issues, but they're less important.

Answer (score 0):

THE FOLLOWING PROOF DOES NOT WORK, but is left up as a challenge for anyone who wants to think about the error (hint: size is definitely an issue).

The Yoneda embedding satisfies the following universal property: if $\mathcal{D}$ is a category with all small colimits, and $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is any functor, then there is an extension of $F$ to $\operatorname{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}}}$ along the Yoneda embedding, which is unique up to natural equivalence.

It follows that $Y_2$ has an inverse (namely, the extension of $Y_1$ to $\mathcal{C}_3$), so it is indeed an equivalence of categories.

Comment: Thanks. A reference was found in nCatLab for the required universal property. It only remains to understand (co)limits now and verify the required property, which I will do shortly. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: False. There are various issues here that prevent this operation from being idempotent.